# C++ overloading >> and<< operators

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
fstream& operator>> (fstream & in, class& obj);

fstream& operator<< (fstream & out, class& obj);
```

---

Is this overloading legal or not?
And what is it's solution?

Actually l am using files in a program with the help of fstream class objects.
So I need to overload >>&<< operators so that such statements can work.

File>>obj;
File<

But would 
ifstream& operator >> (ifstream & , classname& obj)
ofstream& operator >> (ofstream & , classname& obj)

Work for fstream objects?

Comment: Is this a question from a quiz or homework?

Comment: `class` is a language keyword, not a type.   So your examples as written are not valid C++.     If you replace `class` with the name of a valid type for which `fstream` does not already overload the operators, then your examples would be valid declarations  - assuming a `using namespace std` is in effect, and not causing ambiguity.

Comment: Related: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/)

Answer (score 1):

Legal, but you should use the more general forms:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, t& obj);
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const t& obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

In operator overloading, if an operator is overloaded as member, then it must be a member of the object on left side of the operator.The operators ‘<<' and '>>' are called like 'cout << ob1' and 'cin >> ob1'. So if we want to make them a member method, then they must be made members of ostream and istream classes, which is not a good option most of the time. Therefore, these operators are overloaded as global functions with two parameters, cout and object of user defined class.

Comment: it is better if you include an example in your answer